# My centered div isn't quite centered

Tags: html, layout

Good morning everyone. I've looked around on the site, and tried the suggestions from a few of the threads here and I've gotten my div to center, but the left edge of the div is centered, I would like the content within the div centered, and then the div itself centered.

[Here's what I mean.](http://www.emmingerdesign.com/madlab2.html)

Is there maybe a margin hidden in the CSS (It's sort of a mess)?

Comment: There are 3 divs on that page (or 4 if you count the extra end tag); which one?

Answer (score 0):

The width of the *centered* div must be greater than it's content. The **ul** has a width of 515px, so I changed the *centered* div width to 600px:

```
#centered {
    position: relative;
    width: 600px; /* This width must be greater than the content width. */
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: left;
}
```

Comment: Thank you Mario, this was it. It was staring me in the face.